# Visual Studios 2010 find window stuck open

Tags: visual-studio-2010

For some reason my find window for Visual Studios in stuck open, I can't move, resize, minimize or close it. The top control bar is missing. Everything still works, but it is a huge pain to not be able to minimize it or close it. Any ideas of how to fix this?

Comment: Does this happen consistently? (i.e. every time you start Visual Studio)

Comment: What about selecting the window and hitting 'escape'?

Comment: Yes this always happens. Dave, yes hitting escape works. Also I think this is happening due to my graphics card, I know it sounds weird. I have a USB to VGA converter. It will always get messed up on the monitor that uses USB, but the if the find window is on the monitor that uses my graphics card it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I have dual monitors, one of them is connected through a USB to VGA converter. If any visual studios window is on that monitor, it wont render. I'm not sure why, but the solution is to just not put visual studios on that window.